# Android: TranslateAnimation for layout when soft keyboard is shown

Tags: android, sliding

I found [this code](https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo) to make a sliding menu like facebook app. He (who wrote this code) used a FrameLayout to contain 2 views and used TranslateAnimation to show/hide menu. He used `setFillAfter(true)` to keep position of view. In `onAnimationEnd`, he used `view.layout(left, top, right, bottom)` to ensure that views are in correct position.

I modified this code to use with 3 views: leftView, centerView and rightView (Each view in my case is a LinearLayout) like facebook and found a problem: when activity is show leftView (and a part of centerView), if I click an EditText in leftView and soft keyboard is shown, it return to centerView. Similarly, it happens when I click on an ExpandableListView and Childs is shown.

Can anyone help me please?‎. Here is [my code](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38205395/TestErrorSlidingActivity.rar).

Thank you in advance and sorry for my poor English!

Comment: I would suggest looking into this [SlidingMenu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), it's getting quite popular and supports 3 views out of the box.

Comment: I'am trying. Thank your for your helps

Comment: I imported this code but I had a problem. I cannot add android support v4 library to the ExampleListActivity project. I tried to go to Android tools -> Add support Library and file android-support-v4.jar appear in libs folder but I cannot import android.support.v4...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the keyboard retriggers the measurement/layout pass of your FrameLayout.
At this point the layout you manually called gets replaced from the FrameLayout original layout.
To avoid this you have 2 ways:
1) Do not use a FrameLayout (define your own extension of the viewgroup or extend FrameLayout overriding all the methods regarding the measurement/layout of the children)
2) Do not call layout after the animation but rather try using setMargin on your children (if possible)

Obviously the best way would be the first one.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what happen when soft keyboard is shown? I've no ideal what happened with my FrameLayout :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" for activity in manifest.
Worked for me :)